# An equation in *System Identification - Theory for the user*

Tags: dirac-delta, spectra, system-identification

I'm reading *System Identification - Theory for the user* and trapped in (2.66) below

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

I have no idea how the equation (2.66) developed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.